# Cannot import name -> No matching distribution when trying to install

Tags: python, pip, installation, importerror

I have no experience with Python. Just trying to run a program I downloaded from GitHub. Had a lot of problems trying to run it. After adding PATH, and installing a few modules(?), I got stuck:

When I type in "python filename.py", I get the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name: 'SequentialDataSet'

I got the same error with different names. Just typed in "pip install (name)" to fix it. Got the same error again with another name, installed, but now I'm stuck with the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   SequentialDataSet (from versions: ). No matching distribution found
>   for SequentialDataSet.

Let me know if there is any info you need

Thanks

Comment: can you copy/paste the Github link of your program ?

Comment: https://github.com/robbiebarrat/rapping-neural-network#write-song

Comment: Well `SequentialDataSet` does not appear in any file of the code. Look here [https://github.com/robbiebarrat/rapping-neural-network/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SequentialDataSet](https://github.com/robbiebarrat/rapping-neural-network/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SequentialDataSet)

Comment: Noticed that. The question is, why does it come up then?

Comment: I suggest installing miniconda, https://conda.io/miniconda.html, create a virtual environment, then install whatever is missing. I just tried it. Besides the packages listed in [requirements.txt](https://github.com/robbiebarrat/rapping-neural-network/blob/master/requirements.txt), it very likely requires additional [SciPy stack](https://www.scipy.org/stackspec.html) libraries given it's a neural network package. `SequentialDataSet` could be a dependency in the dependency tree, it does not necessarily have to be in the repo

Answer (score 0):

Install [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html), then try this

```
git clone https://github.com/robbiebarrat/rapping-neural-network.git

cd rapping-neural-network/

conda create -p venv -y python=2 scipy 

source activate venv/

pip install -U -r requirements.txt

python deeprap.py
```

output:

```
*Writing the rap 'word by word'*
Alright, building the list of all the rhymes - here are the words that have to be taken into account;

['ve', 'ts', 'cy', 'es', 'ed', 'ke', 'ss', 'ps', 'ft', 'te', '', 'or', 'rn', 'em', 'll', 'le', 'ne', 'me', 'ds', 'hy', 'ry', 'ep', 'ty', 'rk', 'gs', 'ys', 'wn', 'ng', 'lt', 'ny', 'ap', 'ut', 'en', 'im', 'it', 'ch', 'ic', 'ee', 'ly', 'ez', 'ms', 'rd', 'ge', 'er', 'as', 'st', 'tt', 'ns', "'t", 'nt', 'at', 'ck', 'he', 'dy', 'ks', 'ce', 'rl', 'rt', 'pp', 'ls', 'el', 'ib', 'be', 'tz', 'fe', 'de', 'au', 'of', "'s", 'ip', 'on', 'ew', 'os', 'ey', 'sy', 'da', 'an', 're', 'th', 'ld', 'cs', 'op', 'ad', 'se', 'ao', 'ix', 'ct']


Alright, here are all of the possible rhymes from the lyrics it can draw from.
['ve', 'ts', 'cy', 'es', 'ed', 'ke', 'ss', 'ps', 'ft', 'te', '', 'or', 'rn', 'em', 'll', 'le', 'ne', 'me', 'ds', 'hy', 'ry', 'ep', 'ty', 'rk', 'gs', 'ys', 'wn', 'ng', 'lt', 'ny', 'ap', 'ut', 'en', 'im', 'it', 'ch', 'ic', 'ee', 'ly', 'ez', 'ms', 'rd', 'ge', 'er', 'as', 'st', 'tt', 'ns', "'t", 'nt', 'at', 'ck', 'he', 'dy', 'ks', 'ce', 'rl', 'rt', 'pp', 'ls', 'el', 'ib', 'be', 'tz', 'fe', 'de', 'au', 'of', "'s", 'ip', 'on', 'ew', 'os', 'ey', 'sy', 'da', 'an', 're', 'th', 'ld', 'cs', 'op', 'ad', 'se', 'ao', 'ix', 'ct']

Done! Check neural_rap.txt for the finished rap.
```

Comment: Tried "conda create -p venv -y python=2 scipy". Error: win32 hard link failed. Activated successfully. Had to do the "pip install (name)" again. Aaaaand... it stoped at SequentialDataSet :/ Did I do anything wrong? By SOURCE activate venv/ I assume you mean rapping-neural-network?

Comment: So you are on windows?

Comment: Not sure why `Error: win32 hard link failed. ` You may want to read this page, https://www.scipy.org/install.html. `source activate venv/` is just the command to activate the virtual environment `venv` created. I am actually not sure if `source` works on windows. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Met the same problem. Fixed by installing the pybrain from github:

`pip install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip`